# JQuery UI datepicker defaulDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to set a default date in an input box.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/tNpKY/3/

I've tried `defaultDate: new Date(1985, 00, 01)` and also `defaultDate: +7` but none of those are working for me -> The input is still empty.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
}).datepicker( "setDate", new Date() );
```

Comment: This is actually even better. +1

Answer (score 2):

`defaultDate` doesn't set the value of the textbox.

From [the doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate):

> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.

So it doesn't set the value of the input field, it sets the default once you open the datepicker, which your fiddle does.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultDate` is used to provide a default value for date if a user does not fill the form. The actual field can be prepopulated using `val`:

```
$('#date').val('01.02.85');
```